# What are the + (plus) and - (minus) and ? (question mark) in Lichess near elo?

Tags: rating, lichess

What does the +58 mean here? How does a player with higher elo get +58 for beating me with white?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The +58 is how much White gained for winning. The -5 is how much Black lost for losing.

The reason the gain is so much higher is because White had a provisional rating. (This is indicated by the "?" after the 875.) Because White's rating was considered unreliable but Black's was reliable, White was going to gain or lose many points, and Black was going to gain or lose few points. This is a feature of the Glicko-2 rating system used by lichess. According to their [FAQ](https://lichess.org/faq#ratings):

> ... when a player is just starting out, their rating will change very dramatically, potentially several hundred points at a time. But after some games against established players the confidence interval will narrow, and the amount of points gained/lost after each game will decrease.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I thought I understood the + and -, it was `?` I was overlooking.

Comment: I filed a feature req on this https://github.com/lichess-org/lila/issues/11776#issue-1422608602